# How to put a symbol over a wedge

Tags: symbols

I am only having trouble getting the j_t over the wedge. I have posted a pic of what I am trying to get to. I appreciate any help given.

[image]

Comment: `L_t \overset{j_t}{\wedge} R_t`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$L_t{}^{j_t}_{\wedge}R_t$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I think you want the first instance in the following image, which just needs loading `amsmath`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\overwedge}[1]{%
  \mathpalette\stiven@overwedge{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\stiven@overwedge}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{$\m@th#1{}^{#2}_{\wedge}$}}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\binoverwedge}[1]{\mathbin{\overwedge{#1}}}

\begin{document}

$L_t \overset{j_t}{\wedge} R_t$
\quad
$L_t \overwedge{j_t} R_t$
\quad
$L_t \binoverwedge{j_t} R_t$

\end{document}
```

[image]